# How to call API route in WordPress created

Tags: laravel, api

I am working on laravel and want to call laravel API in WordPress my route is

```
    Route::post('/login','AuthController@login');
Route::post('/register','AuthController@register');
Route::middleware ('auth:api')->post('/logout',"AuthController@logout");
```

When I call it in WordPress using curl I get error method not allowed HTTP exception
and API/user work fine.

Comment: Show us your code that you are using to call the Laravel endpoint.

Comment: I define it in env file and the  add in service and make a controller to call it

Comment: @hassankhan can u add `csrf_token` in header ? 
 if not then add otherwise add url in `verifyCsrfToken` middleware to skip csrf_token protecction

Comment: @JigneshJoisar Method not allowed exception means you haven't sent the request with the right method. Has nothing to do with the csrf token.

Comment: @ChinLeung this is code of end points
PASSPORT_LOGIN_ENDPOINT="http:/localhost:8080/admin/topstars/public/oauth/token"
PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID=2
PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET=VFbLy9IkhdDYRhRe5ZKwulQHRIDTV5MrKrMUjDSQ

Comment: @ChinLeung    localhost:8080 is example original it contains the website url

Comment: I need to see how you are sending the request, not the endpoints.

Comment: i have resolve the issue as i am not passing the username and password in api 
i did it by passing hardcoded credentials but i am stuck on passing them that all user can login who are register

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your cURL call uses the `POST` http method. You may also need to add a `_method` field to your data:

```
"_method" => "POST"
```